# Use variables to get lmList() in R

Tags: r, linear-regression

I have data that I read in as a data.table. It would look something like this:

```
d <- data.table(TYPE = c('A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C'),
                CLASS = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 2, 1),
                NUM = c(48, 23, 32, 56, 75, 45, 76))
```

If I run `fits <- lmList(NUM ~ TYPE | CLASS, data = d)` it runs, however, if I try to store the column names into variables (to reduce hard coding) and run it like this:

```
Y <- 'NUM'
X <- 'TYPE'
grp <- 'CLASS'
fits <- lmList(Y ~ X | grp, data = d)
```

I get this error:

```
Warning messages:
1: In storage.mode(v) <- "double" : NAs introduced by coercion
2: In lmList(Y ~ X | grp, data = d) :
  Fitting failed for 1 group(s), probably because a factor only had one level:
  contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels
```

I also tried `fits <- lmList(as.name(Y) ~ as.name(X) | as.name(grp), data = d)` and I get this error:

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = as.name(Y) ~ as.name(X) + as.name(grp),  : 
  object is not a matrix
```

Something else I tried was:

```
fits <- lmList(eval(paste(Y ~ X | grp, data = d)))
```

Which resulted in:

```
Error in UseMethod("lmList") : 
  no applicable method for 'lmList' applied to an object of class "character"
```

What am I doing wrong here? Any help or advice is welcome. Thanks!

**Update**
Here is a [link](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/lme4/versions/1.1-17/topics/lmList) to `lmList` for reference.

Comment: Where does `lmList` come from? Note that formulas are not made up of strings. If you need to make a formula from strings, use `reformulate()`.

Comment: `lmList` is from the `library(lme4)`

Comment: Either `lme4` or `nlme` will load it. `nlme` masks `lme4`.

Comment: Using `fits <- reformulate(lmList(Y ~ X | grp, data = d))` produces:
`Error in reformulate(lmList(Y ~ X | grp, data = d)) : 
  'termlabels' must be a character vector of length at least one
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In storage.mode(v) <- "double" : NAs introduced by coercion
2: 1 error caught in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]): contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels`

Comment: In addition `fits <- as.formula(lmList(Y ~ X | grp, data = d))` results in `Warning messages:
1: In storage.mode(v) <- "double" : NAs introduced by coercion
2: 1 error caught in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]): contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels`

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late to the party, but I just had this problem.
I am answering this for future searchers.
You have to treat the formula as a text string in `paste()`.
Try:

```
fits <- lmList(as.formula(paste(Y, " ~ ", X, " | grp")), data = d)
```